# Study the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan x }{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Study the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan x }{x^2}dx$

I've seen a proof which goes like this.

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\arctan x}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}} = \frac{\pi}{2} > 0$$

The integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ is a well-known convergent integral hence, by comparison we conclude that $\int_1^\infty \frac{\arctan x }{x^2}dx$ converges.

I've learn that if $g(x) \le f(x)$ then $\int_a^b g(x) \le \int_a^b f(x)$, but I'm not sure what was done here. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 3):

Others have shown how to do this with the limit comparison test.  I thought I'd just point out that an antiderivative is available:

$$ \int \dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x^2}\; dx = 
-\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x} + \ln \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} + c$$
so that your improper integral can be evaluated:

$$ \int_1^\infty \dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x^2}\; dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(
-\dfrac{\arctan(x)}{x} + \ln \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) - \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{4} + \ln \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{4} + \dfrac{\ln 2}{2} $$

Answer (score 2):

The limit comparison test (for improper integrals) was used to prove convergence of $\int_1^\infty \arctan(x)/x^2\, dx$.